# How to run PHP mail scripts in Windows 7?

Tags: php, forms, email, xampp

I am trying to run a PHP mail script in my local computer (Windows 7) using xampp. I can run the PHP mail form successfully but while sending the e-mail it shows this message-

```
**Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\sendeail.php on line 146**
```

How to fix this, or is it possible to send email from my local computer using xampp any other way?

Comment: This error message is being generated by your mail server, not by PHP. In all probability, it indicates that you have the SMTP server set incorrectly in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

After viewing so many YouTube videos and blogs, this is what worked for me:

1. Make sure your SMTP Service Status shows ACTIVATED --> go to [this URL](http://iaji.net/how-to-send-email-within-xampp.html) to get a nice demo.
2. Go to [this URL](http://www.google.com/settings/security), sign in with your gmail account you'll be using to test your php email, then in the Security tab, locate "Access for less secure apps" then click Enable (you can always Disable it again after your php email tests).
3. Start with a brand new `php.ini` file (hopefully you made a copy of your orignal `php.ini`). The reason for this is so you'll have a `php.ini` that hasn't been tampered with. These following lines in the `php.ini` must be either commented (have a leading `;`) or uncommented (don't have a leading `;`), this is crucial):

   ```
   [mail function]
   ; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
   ;SMTP = localhost
   ;smtp_port = 25

   sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

   ;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

   extension=php_openssl.dll
   ```

   EVERYTHING ELSE in the `php.ini` YOU LEAVE ALONE.

   **So let's double check that these lines are commented (have a leading `;`):**

   ```
   ;SMTP= local host 
   ;smtp_port = 25
   ;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
   ```
4. Then `sendmail.ini` must be as follows - I basically copied the whole thing here.  Where it says `your.email.gmail` type in your own gmail address, same thing with the password:

   ```
   [sendmail]
   ; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
   ; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
   ; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
   ; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
   ; application.

   smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

   ; smtp port (normally 25)

   smtp_port=465

   ; SMTPS (SSL) support
   ;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
   ;   ssl  = alway use SSL
   ;   tls  = always use TLS
   ;   none = never try to use SSL

   smtp_ssl=auto

   ; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
   ; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
   ; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

   ;default_domain=mydomain.com

   ; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
   ; uncomment to enable logging

   error_logfile=error.log

   ; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
   ; uncomment to enable debugging

   ;debug_logfile=debug.log

   ; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

   auth_username=your.email@gmail.com
   auth_password=your email password

   ; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
   ; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

   pop3_server=
   pop3_username=
   pop3_password=

   ; force the sender to always be the following email address
   ; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
   ; the "From: " header of the message content

   force_sender=

   ; force the sender to always be the following email address
   ; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
   ; the "To: " header of the message content

   force_recipient=

   ; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
   ; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

   hostname=
   ```